# MVC Visual Studio "circular dependency"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, circular-dependency

I have got a problem with "circular dependency" at the moment. I have got error because I have to add file .dll to another project but reference already exist in this project which I want to add. I don`t know what I have to do?

```
Error   1   SportsStore.WebUI.accessor: The reference to 'SportsStore.WebUI.dll' was not found in the list of this projects references  SportsStore.UnitTests
```

[image]

Comment: So you have a reference to the WebUI assembly in the UnitTests assembly, but why would you have a reference to the UnitTests assembly from the WebUI assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the screenshot you just posted it looks like you are adding the **SportsStore.WebUI** project as a reference to the **SportsStore.UnitTests** and this failed because of a circular dependency. Does this mean your WebUI project already references the UnitTests project? If it does, then you have a problem with your design, because 'real' code should never reference test projects.

Now, in general, if you want to solve circular dependencies you could simply extract the common part in an separate assembly. Instead of the projects referencing each other, they'll reference that common assembly instead.